# Update Column based on another field

Tags: mysql

My table is labeled 'media'
I have a field called 'mediatypeID' it contains data like book, magazine.
I have a field called 'location' where that piece of media is located. So for instance books are located on shelf1
I have changed the location of my books and I need to edit that information.
I want to search db table 'media' where the media type is 'book' and change the data in the field location  to 'shelf3'.

how do I create a statement to do this.
Thank you

Comment: Putting "MySQL" plus your question title [into Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+Update+Column+based+on+another+field) shows many, many answers to your question. You're expected to do at least this level of effort *before* posting a SO question.

Comment: Where's your query?  Have you even tried something???  Have you tried to Google your question???  There are tons of example online. 
 Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE media SET location='shelf3' WHERE mediatypeID='book'`